# Desire 2 Learn Org Unit ID

Tags: desire2learn

What is the API call for finding a particular orgUnit ID for a particular course? I am trying to pull grades and a class list from API but I can not do it without the orgUnitID

Answer (score 0):

There's potentially a few ways to go about this, depending on the kind of use-case you're in. Firstly, you can traverse the organizational structure to find the details of the course offering you're looking for. Start from the organization's node (the root org) and use [the route to retrieve an org's descendants](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-orgstructure-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-descendants-) to work your way down: you'll want to restrict this call to only course-offering type nodes (org unit type ID '3' by default). This process will almost certainly require fetching a large amount of data, and then parsing through it.

If you know the course offering's *Code* (the unique identifier your organization uses to define course offerings), or the name, then you can likely find the offering in the list of descendants by matching against those values.

You can also make this search at a smaller scope in a number of ways:

- If you already know the Org Unit ID for a node in the structure that's related to the course offering (for example, the *Department* or *Semester* that's a parent of the course offering), you can start your search from *that* node and you'll have a lot fewer nodes to parse through.
- If your calling user context (or a user context that you know, and can authenticate as) is enrolled in the course offering, or in a known parent org (like a Department), then you can [fetch the list of all that user's enrollments](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-myenrollments-), and parse through those to find the single course offering you're looking for. (Note that this enrollments route sends back data as a paged result set, and not as a simple JSON array, so you may have to make several calls to work your way through a number of data pages before finding the one you want.)

In all these scenarios, the process will end up with you retrieving a JSON structure that will contain the Org Unit ID which you can then persist and use directly later.